# Updating picturebox causes performance issues

Tags: c#, winforms, streaming

I have an app that contains a picture box which updates images from a live camera every time a new image gets loaded into the camera buffer. My problem is that whenever I'm getting this live feed, the whole app becomes very slow and (sometimes) unresponsive. I have a separate thread which basically does all the imaging steps and then puts the new image in the picture box. I'm kind of stuck on how to fix the issue and I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas? I'm not sure what kind of code you need but here is the `ImageUpdated` event that gets the image and sticks it on the `PictureBox`. Thanks for any help!

```
void CurrentCamera_ImageUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lock (CurrentCamera.image)
        {
            if (CurrentCamera != null && CurrentCamera.image != null && !changeCam)
            {
                videoImage = CurrentCamera.videoImage;
                if (CurrentCamera.videoImage != null && this.IsHandleCreated)
                {
                    Bitmap tmp = new Bitmap(CurrentCamera.image.Width, CurrentCamera.image.Height);
                    //Creates a crosshair on the image
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(tmp))
                    {
                        g.DrawImage(CurrentCamera.image, new Point(0, 0));
                        g.DrawLine(crosshairPen, new Point(CurrentCamera.image.Width / 2, 0), new Point(CurrentCamera.image.Width / 2, (CurrentCamera.image.Height)));
                        g.DrawLine(crosshairPen, new Point(0, CurrentCamera.image.Height / 2), new Point((CurrentCamera.image.Width), CurrentCamera.image.Height / 2));
                        g.DrawEllipse(crosshairPen, (CurrentCamera.image.Width / 2) - crosshairRadius, (CurrentCamera.image.Height / 2) - crosshairRadius, crosshairRadius * 2, crosshairRadius * 2);
                    }
                    pictureBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = tmp;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: Realized that just as you commented. Changed.

Comment: I'm guessing here, you are calling BeginInvoke() which does some work asynchronously, while images come very fast, and you end up with few such invokes waiting to get executed; Maybe you should try to check IAsyncResult of the previous BeginInvoke call and if method hadn't completed, skip the setting of the image to the pictureBox. You will end up losing some frames but the application won't be unresponsive. Again, I'm just guessing it.

Comment: Also, maybe some Exceptions are catch but you don't see it because of your empty catch block

Comment: There are no exceptions, but I did try your first suggestion and it helped a little bit but the performance is still really bad. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Have you considered just embedding a DirectX drawing surface or openGL canvas onto the form? It's pretty painless and hardware acceleration and handles all that fun, low level stuff for you.

Comment: As you work with GDI+ you will not be able to achieve high-speed results. It's a limitation of GDI+. As Vaughan suggest, a DirectX or rather DirectShow surface will be better as it is more low-level. check out f.ex. http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/ for a wrapper for .Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comment, I think that this might speed up a little bit. First, if the image is't set on the pictureBox1, then don't set another. Second, because of using pictureBox, it is optimized not to have flicker so you can draw the crosshair in your PaintEvent method handler for the pictureBox1. This is a little bit improved code that avoids double Bitmap drawing, then you should speed up as much as you can `CurrentCamera_ImageUpdated` method execution because new images come very fast, C# code can't handle that much drawing even on a high performance machine. Start from here, and keep on improving.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox1_Paint);
    }

    void  pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            int width = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
            int height = pictureBox1.Image.Height;
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(crosshairPen, new Point(width / 2, 0), new Point(width / 2, height));
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(crosshairPen, new Point(0, pictureBox1.Image.Height / 2), new Point(width, height / 2));
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(crosshairPen, (width / 2) - crosshairRadius, (height / 2) - crosshairRadius, crosshairRadius * 2, crosshairRadius * 2);
        }
    } 
    IAsyncResult result = null;
    void CurrentCamera_ImageUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (CurrentCamera.image)
            {
                if (CurrentCamera != null && CurrentCamera.image != null && !changeCam)
                {
                    videoImage = CurrentCamera.videoImage;
                    if (CurrentCamera.videoImage != null && this.IsHandleCreated)
                    {
                        if (result != null && result.IsCompleted)
                        {
                            result = pictureBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                pictureBox1.Image = CurrentCamera.videoImage;
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```